# How to have two project in .net solution one targeting 4.0 framework and other one 4.5 framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a module which is using .Net 4.5 features and our application works for XP users also. So I was thinking of moving this .net 4.5 dependent module to separate project. How can I have a solution which is having two projects targeting to different version?

Comment: No, You can't.  ou have to separate project and dll also.

Comment: What problems have you encountered in trying to do so? Since the framework version is set in the *project* settings

Comment: First, 4.5 is a binary replacement for 4.0. Even projects that target 4.0 actually run on 4.5. Second, nothing prevents you from changing the target framework of individual projects.

Comment: In other words, why do you want to keep one project as 4.0 when it will run as 4.5 anyway?

Comment: Just noticed the XP requirement. In this case it's better to use the Microsoft.Bcl.Async, Microsoft.Bcl.HttpClient packages to add async, HttpClient etc functionality to 4.0 instead of having a separate 4.5 project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each project in a solution is targeting it's specific version of .NET, so there is nothing special to that, **BUT** you can NOT reference that project/module targeting .NET 4.5 from the .NET 4.0 project.

If you need to target .NET 4.5 for some module your main application must also target .NET 4.5, so if there is no way around that features you need to ditch XP support, which is IMO not a bad thing as XP is not a supported OS anymore.

IF that feature from .NET 4.5 is the `async`/`await`-feature you could use the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)-package an keep targeting .NET 4.0...

Comment: Note that the 4.0 will use the 4.5 runtime anyway.

Comment: Then a better option would be to use Microsoft.Bcl.Async and HttpClient instead of having a 4.5 project that can never work in XP

Comment: Thank you everyone. The problem is indeed usage of async/await. About this Microsoft.Bcl.Async is it so that its API is exactly the same whats with .net 4.5 TPL?

Comment: @Shery: Yes and no: `async`/`await` has the same syntax/API, but some other minor stuff is different or not existent. Like `Task.Run` is .NET 4.5 only, but you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew`...