# In VS2017, is it possible to step-through code between projects that use different frameworks?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, .net-framework-version

My VS2017 solution has a mixture of projects that use .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.7, as we're part way through migrating from the former to the latter.

I need to debug the ASMX web service project, which is at 4.7.  The client project is at 3.5.  The web service also calls methods in DLLs in projects at 3.5.  This all works fine, and has been stable for some time.

I used to be able to set a break at the web service call, and then F11 step into the (local IIS) web service and thus debug the latter.

Now I get

```
Unable to automatically step into server. unable to determine a stopping location
```

I've verified that all the projects are set to `Debug` and not `Release`.

If I change all the projects to use .NET 4.7, it works - stepping through into the web service lets me debug it.

We're not ready to migrate all the projects to 4.7, though.

Is it possible to set up VS2017 so that step-through debugging is possible, even though the framework versions are different?

Comment: Usually when I debug a service and client app I right click on the solution and set my startup projects to the service and client app.  This way I can step through the code in both projects

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that we couldn't use two .NET Framework versions in the different projects which has the reference relationship. If the two projects use the same dll file but different versions, it would have the conflict if one project refer to another project during debugging time. Actually it looks like one solution which includes two projects like this case:

[How to have two project in .net solution one targeting 4.0 framework and other one 4.5 framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361299/how-to-have-two-project-in-net-solution-one-targeting-4-0-framework-and-other-o)